# What does "potential realities splitting in two" mean?

Tags: black-mirror, bandersnatch

In his notes, Davies repeatedly sketched a glyph
which to him represented multiple fates, **potential realities splitting in two**.
It was the start of his complete mental collapse. Davies became convinced
he had no control over his fate because his wife was spiking him with
psychoactive drugs at behest of a demon called Pax, a sort of lion figure
who he claimed he'd seen in a vision, and who ended up being incorporated into the book.

What does "potential realities splitting in two" mean?

Sounds like physics term to me.

Comment: Hey, Jake… can you explain how any of that detail matters? Most obviously, who is Davies?

If you dropped all the rest and simply Asked 'What does "potential realities splitting in two" mean?' what would be lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me that sounds like the science fiction concept of alternate universes diverging, and/or the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics.

> The many-worlds interpretation (MWI) is an interpretation of quantum mechanics that asserts that the universal wavefunction is objectively real, and that there is no wavefunction collapse.[2] This implies that all possible outcomes of quantum measurements are physically realized in some "world" or universe.[3] In contrast to some other interpretations, such as the Copenhagen interpretation, the evolution of reality as a whole in MWI is rigidly deterministic.[2] Many-worlds is also called the relative state formulation or the Everett interpretation, after physicist Hugh Everett, who first proposed it in 1957.[4][5] Bryce DeWitt popularized the formulation and named it many-worlds in the 1960s and 1970s.[1][6][7][2]
>
> In many-worlds, the subjective appearance of wavefunction collapse is explained by the mechanism of quantum decoherence. Decoherence approaches to interpreting quantum theory have been widely explored and developed since the 1970s,[8][9][10] and have become quite popular. MWI is now considered a mainstream interpretation along with the other decoherence interpretations, collapse theories (including the Copenhagen interpretation), and hidden variable theories such as Bohmian mechanics.
>
> The many-worlds interpretation implies that there are very—perhaps infinitely[11]—many universes. It is one of many multiverse hypotheses in physics and philosophy. MWI views time as a many-branched tree, wherein every possible quantum outcome is realised. This is intended to resolve some paradoxes of quantum theory, such as the EPR paradox[5]:462[2]:118 and Schrödinger's cat,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) since every possible outcome of a quantum event exists in its own universe.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation%5B1%5D)

The idea that the universe is constantly branching off into different alternate universes so that each possible outcome of an event happens in one of more alternate universes is a very common story element in science fiction, going back at least as far as Murray Leinster's "Sideways in Time", *Astounding stories*, June 1934.

And the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics is probably the best known scientific justification for believing that alternate universes could possibly be real.

So my guess is that the character Davies in *Black Mirror* "Bandersnatch" is thinking about the science fiction concept of alternate universes constantly branching off and diverging from each other, and/or the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics.

I note that almost all works of fiction involve imaginary people, places, things, and events which can be proven not to exist in our reality, and thus must be in alternate universes.  Thus it seems to me those works of fiction exist in fictional universes where alternate universes - the universe of the story and the universe of the reader - are real, and thus that every time that someone suspends disbelief to enjoy a work of fiction they are accepting, at least for the moment, the existence of alternate universes.